# PHP Memory Allocation Limit Causes

Tags: php, linux, memory, out-of-memory, dev-to-production

I have 2 servers

Both server's have the same php memory_limit of 128M of data.

My Dev Server runs a script just fine, while on my prod server I am receiving a Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in ...

My question is what are other reasons I would be running out of memory in the prod environment even though my php memory_limits are the same?

Comment: Are they using the same version of php?

Comment: ...almost anything... normally it's a matter of input/output, you'd make sure that with the exact same input & output of data (for instance: make sure your dev database is the same as your production database for this test). But then again: if your dev stays _just_ under, and production _just_ over, any simple minor version change of any module can cause this.

Comment: This mostly depends on what you are doing with your data. If have a bad routine it could be running on a dev server with little test data. Just check the line of code of your error message.

Comment: PHP is a modular & http has parameters which boundaries memories with RLimitCPU,RLimitNPROC, RLimitMEM variables which can be optimized as per your need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preface**

PHP is module that runs top of Apache [HTTPD Server] this involves linking the php interpreter against a library of hooks published by the webserver

**Cause**

```
Now it can exhaust due to scripts running allocating memory [RAM] & reach its threshold & get such errors.

Example big loops running & saving lots of data in memory which may over RUN the Memory
```

**Possible Optimization you can do**

```
memory_limit = 32M to your server's main php.ini file (recommended, if you have access)
php_value memory_limit 32M in your .htaccess file in the
```

These are some work around for pages where you RUN out of Memory

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); overrides the default PHP memory limit (On individual php pages wherever you need extra memory)
```

Also some optimization you can do on HTTP Server (apache.conf or http.conf)

`RLimitCPU,RLimitNPROC, RLimitMEM parameters can be adusted`

Since you are running out of Memory you can adjust RLimitMEM

```
Syntax: RLimitMEM soft-bytes [hard-bytes]
Example: RLimitMEM 1048576 2097152

This directive sets the soft and hard limits for maximum memory usage of a process in bytes. It takes one or two parameters. The first parameter sets the soft resource limit for all processes. The second parameter sets the maximum resource limit. Either parameter can be a number, or ``max'', which indicates to the server that the limit should match the maximum allowed by the operating system configuration. Raising the maximum resource limit requires the server to be running as the user ``root'' or in the initial start-up phase.
```

You can put the lines in .htaccess files too [since in shared hosting you didnt have access to php.ini & http.conf files